# why the kubernetes pod use the none network instead of the bridge network on the worker node?

Tags: kubernetes

Can someone please let me know why the kubernetes pod use the none network instead of the bridge network on the worker node?

I Setup a kubernetes cluster by use kubo.

```
The worker node by default will have 3 docker network.

NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER
30bbbc954768        bridge              bridge              
c8cb510d1646        host                host                
5e6b770e7aa6        none                null
```

The docker default network is bridge
    $>docker network inspect bridge

```
"Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
```

But if I use kubectl run  command to start a pod

```
kubectl run -it --image nginx bash
```

on the work node there will be two container start

```
7cf6061fe0b8    40960efd7b8f     "nginx -g 'daemon off"   33 minutes ago      
Up 33 minutes      k8s_bash_bash-325157647-ns4xj_default_9d5ea60e-cf74-11e7-9ae8-00505686d000_2

37c51d605b16        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0   "/pause"             
35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes  k8s_POD_bash-325157647-ns4xj_default_9d5ea60e-cf74-11e7-9ae8-00505686d000_0
```

if we run docker inspect 37c51d605b16
we can see it will use “none”

```
"Networks": {
            "none": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
```

So why kubernetes will use the none network for communication?

Comment: As far as I know, Kubernetes use CNI plugin which are calico, weave etc. I have added link perhaps it might give you reasonable thoughts https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/network-plugins/

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes uses an overlay network to manage pod-to-pod communication on the same or different hosts. Each pod gets a single IP address for all containers in that pod. A `pause` container is created to hold the network namespace and thus reserve the IP address, which is useful when containers restart, as they get the same IP.

The pod has its own ethernet adapter, say `eth0` which is mapped to a virtual ethernet adapter on the host say `veth0xx`, in the root network namespace, which in turn is connected to a network bridge `docker0` or `cbr0`.

In my Kubernetes setup, with Project Calico as the overlay network CNI plugin, calico creates an ethernet adapter in each pod and maps it to a virtual adapter on the host (name format `calic[0-9a-z]`). This virtual adaptor is connected to a Linux ethernet bridge. IP table rules filter packets to this bridge and then onto the CNI plugin provider, in my case Calico which is able to redirect the packet to the correct pod.

So your containers are in the `none` docker network as docker networking is disabled in your Kubernetes setup, as it's using the overlay network via a CNI plugin. Kubernetes doesn't handle networking but delegates it to the underlying CNI plugin.